# How can I count the number of block of “1” of a given value in a matrix?

Tags: matlab

The numbers of the matrix have already been dealed,only containing "0" and "1".Now I want to find blocks of "1",namely if two or more "1" stand nearby，located left,right,up and down.For exmaple,here is a matrix:

```
1 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0
```

the sum of blocks is 3.
how to use matlab to solve this problem?
many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a connected components problem to me. Steve from Mathworks has written 8 articles about it on his [blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/category/connected-components/). See part 1 to 7.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to find connected components in the matrix with the help of functions from the Image Processing Toolbox (as was pointed out by [@Maurits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7695403/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-block-of-1-of-a-given-value-in-a-matrix/7696366#7696366))

In case you are still having problems, consider the following code:

```
%# matrix
A = [
    1 1 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1
    1 0 1 0 1 1
    1 0 0 0 0 0
];
BW = logical(A);

%# find connected components (4-connected neighborhood)
CC = bwconncomp(BW, 4);

%# find blocks with two or more connected 1's
idx = ( cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList) > 1 );
num = sum(idx);
```

the answer as expected:

```
>> num
ans =
     3
```

As an extra step, we can plot the matrices to help visualize the result:

```
%# update connected components to those found only
CC.PixelIdxList = CC.PixelIdxList(idx);       %# pixel list
CC.NumObjects = sum(idx);                     %# number of blocks

%# show matrix with blocks found
RGB = label2rgb(labelmatrix(CC), 'lines', [0 0 0]);
h(1) = subplot(121); imshow(BW)
h(2) = subplot(122); imshow(RGB)
title( sprintf('Number of blocks = %d',CC.NumObjects) )

%# plot grid lines
X = 1:size(A,2); Y = 1:size(A,1);
vx = repmat(X+0.5,[2 1]); vx(end+1,:) = NaN;
vy = repmat([Y(1)-0.5;Y(end)+0.5;NaN],[1 size(vx,2)]);
hy = repmat(Y+0.5,[2 1]); hy(end+1,:) = NaN;
hx = repmat([X(1)-0.5;X(end)+0.5;NaN],[1 size(hy,2)]);
line('XData',[vx(:);hx(:)], 'YData',[vy(:);hy(:)], 'Parent',h(1), ...
    'LineWidth',1, 'Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8], 'HandleVisibility','off')
line('XData',[vx(:);hx(:)], 'YData',[vy(:);hy(:)], 'Parent',h(2), ...
    'LineWidth',1, 'Color',[0.8 0.8 0.8], 'HandleVisibility','off')
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough for me, sorry.

If you want to find the greatest sum by line or column (this gives the result you provided), use:

```
max( max( sum(A,1) ) , max( sum(A,2) ) )
```

Where: `sum(A,1)`,`sum(A,2)` returns a the sum along column, line of A as a vector. Inner `max()` select the greatest value along each vector and outer `max()` returns the greatest of each greatest bycol,byline sums.

Comment: (comment for my downvoter:) Ok, this is not a great answer. I shouldn't try to answer questions I do not fully understand.

Comment: I was the one who downvoted (sorry should have put a comment)... In fact if you look at the history of edits, you will see that the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9d0beb93-6de6-40fc-8bfe-affd64abbc93/view-source) was indeed in a matrix form, it's just that the OP forgot to correctly format the code, thus appearing as a single line. I am willing to remove my downvote (but you should edit it first since my vote is locked by now), otherwise I think this should be deleted..

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice that one has to click the 'source' link on the history. You made my day ;) Still, I can not interpret his question and basically would make the same answer (I therefore won't edit it, keeping your downvote as a reminder that I should be carefull to fully understand before answering). No offense taken.